# deleting elements in particular locations except some locations

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector

I knew how to erase the c++ vector elements from specified locations. Suppose I have vector A=[0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1]. I want to erase  the elements in the 4 locations, locations are stored in vector B=[1 4 7 8].This I can do like this:

```
 sort (B.begin(), B.end());
 for(int i=B.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
       A.erase(A.begin() + B[i]);
     }
```

Problem:  I have vector C =[ 3 4]. The sizes of vector C  is always less than size of B. Now I have to erase the B.size() elements in A as shown by above code. The condition here is if any indexes of B are same as indexes of C, one should change the indexes of B so that none of the indexes of B are same as C. This means that the indexes of B can be changed, but the size should be same. For this case, the indexes of B can be B=[1 2 7 8]. Now B has indexes which doesnot contains the index of C and I can apply above code.

Can anyone suggest me how to get this?

Comment: For this case, the indexes of B can be B=[1 2 7 8].
They can also be [1 5 7 8] or [1 6 7 8]. How do you decide?

Comment: ya they can be others also, but indexes should not be the indexes of C. for that may be we can use rand () function.

Comment: So you already have a fair idea what is required! Why don't you go ahead and give it a try before asking for help here?

Comment: maybe you can make use of [set_difference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/) and [set_intersection](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/) here

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt:

```
#include <random>       // std::mt19937, std::uniform_int_distribution
#include <algorithm>    // std::set_difference, std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector

//Generate a random number called here rdmNb using <random>
//std::mt19937 gen(seed);
//std::uniform_int_distribution<int> rdmNb(0, A.size-1));

int main ()
{

//Data initialization (using C++11)
std::vector<int> vA = {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1};
std::vector<int> vB = { 1, 2, 7, 8};
std::vector<int> vC = {3, 4};
int rdmNb=1; //just so it compiles (replace by the random generator function)

//Code
std::vector<int> vD(vB.size(),-1);
std::vector<int>::iterator endIt;

std::sort (vB.begin(), vB.end());
std::sort (vC.begin(), vC.end());

do {
    endIt = std::set_difference (vB.begin(), vB.end(),vC.begin(), vC.end(), vD.begin() );
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it(endIt); it< vD.end(); it++) {
        *it = rdmNb;
        vB = vD;
    }
} while (*(dD.end()-1)==0); //while (endIt!=vD.end());

//Your normal code:
for(int i=vD.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    vA.erase(vA.begin() + vD[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```